# Asset catalogues and multiple targets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, asset-catalog

Before I start and move towards the use of Asset Catalogues (which seems the only option in Xcode 6, apart from manually manipulating the info.plist) I would like to ask if there is a good way to have different asset catalogues for different build targets.

I have multiple targets for different Apps using the same code base. So far I had different folders for each target with the icons etc. and only included the ones I wanted.

How do I do this with asset catalogues, or what is the best way to deal with a situation like this in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have several "Icon App" in the same XCAssets file (right-click + New App Icon). Then you can select which "Icon app" you want to use for each of your target.